# Pixels, as Double in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I need to build a printing control in WPF.

The control is a Canvas, the user can select a size (A3, A4 or custom)
The user also can add some objets (labels, grids) on that canvas, and I need to save its positions to eventually print it.

An example is the Margin (Thickness) property:

> Public Property **Left** As Double
>   Member of *System.Windows.Thickness*
>
> Summary:
>   Gets or sets the width, in pixels, of the left side of the bounding rectangle.
>
> Return Values:
>   A **System.Double** that represents **the width, in pixels**,
>   of the left side of the bounding rectangle for this instance of
>   System.Windows.Thickness. A pixel is equal to 1/96 on an inch. The default is 0.

How a value in pixels is `Double`? Can I have 1.5 pixels?
In what should I save the position of each control in my Canvas (say, in the database), in pixels, inches, cm, mm?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote:

> a pixel is equal to 1/96 on an inch

Then it can be a floating point number. Rounding will be operated at the end of the rendering for your device (and it can be taken in account for anti-aliasing, for example). I agree FP math and operations are much slower but at least you have coherence for the API (and rounding precision/method can be modified).

> In what should I save the position of each control in my Canvas (say, in the database), in pixels, inches, cm, mm?

It depends, what kind of application you're developing? That "layouts" will be shared across different users or they're per user? What kind of *page* you use for your controls? Fixed size page? If fixed you may use whatever you want as unit of measure (pixel too), if it's dynamic (based on screen resolution) you may need to convert them to a percentage.

Comment: as I wrote, I do something similar to Crystal Reports. I need to indicate to an field its location, then in that field will appear some text. The format of canvas can be standard A3, A4 or custom sized paper...

Comment: Sorry, I did miss some words! I **think** if you're working with a page you should use a typographic unit of measure (anyway your users will see their own unit) so I would keep pixel (defined as 1/96 of inch) as "neutral" unit. In this way if user change unit of measure for the report you'll be able to update UI without any change to underlying data. Of course it's an arbitrary choice, Microsoft Reports, for example, uses always inches and points as "neutral" unit.

Answer (score 0):

WPF uses sub-pixel rendering, many claim it makes some things look blurry, if you use layout rounding that will snap all the elements to whole pixel values and make things look clearer.

Setting "SnapsToDevicePixels" on the main window should allow you to have int values.

Comment: So, when I save an object "location" in a database, should I use Doubles or Integers?

Comment: Since WPF can use doubles I would allow for that flexibility in the database. However, if you're always going to use SnapsToDevicePixels for applications that use that database field then you could store location as integers.

Comment: I guess animations wouldn't be very fluent if it werd integers but I know that was not the real question